# problem with adding new node to elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

i want to add new node to elastic cluster by enrollment token but i got the error below

```
E:\node-1\bin>elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token.bat -s node
```

18:44:40.729 [main] ERROR org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.enrollment.ExternalEnrollmentTokenGenerator - Error 400when calling GET http://192.168.99.135:9200/_security/api_key. ResponseBody: {error=no handler found for uri [/_security/api_key] and method [POST]}
Unable to create enrollment token for scope [node]

ERROR: Unexpected response code [400] from calling POST http://192.168.99.135:9200/_security/api_key

any solution will be highly appreciated

Comment: Try to run the `elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token.bat -s node` command when elasticsearch running in another tab.

Comment: it is already running

Comment: just to rule out the obvious, is the security feature enabled? what is the version of elasticsearch?

Comment: now i got the token when i use this token for new node i get this error      ERROR: Skipping security auto configuration because it appears that the node is not starting up for the first time. The node might already be part of a cluster and this auto setup utility is designed to configure Security for new clusters only.

Comment: the enrollment process works only for the initial cluster bootstrap. It won't attempt to configure nodes that have already started